# Enviando email por localhost

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estou colocando no meu sistema em PHP o PHPMail e quero testar.
Eu uso MAMP.
Alguém sabe qual HOST deve-se colocar para enviar email? No caso, o sistema está sendo rodado local, ou seja, localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Crie um arquivo php chamado teste por exemplo e inclua a classe `PHPMailerAutoload.php` e configure os parametros exemplo:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com.br'; // SMTP DO SEU EMAIL
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "seuEmail@yahoo.com"; // SEU EMAIL
$mail->Password = "SuaSenha"; // SUA SENHA
$mail->setFrom('seuEmail@yahoo.com', 'Seu nome');
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@gmail.com', 'Reply');
$mail->addAddress('emaildeDestinatario@gmail.com', 'NomeDestinatario');
$mail->Subject = 'Titulo do Texto do Teste';
$mail->Body = 'Mensagem de texto DO Teste';

if (!$mail->send()) {
   echo "Ocorreu algum problema e não conseguimos entregar o seu email: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
   echo "Mensagem enviada!";
}
```

add openssl

primeiro va ate o seu php.ini e coloque:

```
[PHP_OPENSSL]
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

e olhe se existe a `php_openssl.dll` dentro da pasta ext do php

crie um arquivo `teste.php` e coloque `phpinfo()` e verifique se esta habilitado.

Comment: teste e o código assim rodou até antes do IF. Não apareceu nenhuma das mensagens! Tens alguma dica?

Comment: verifique se o openSSL esta habilitado no seu php.ini

Comment: eu nem encontrei esse openSSL no meu arquivo php.ini.
Devo adicionar ele no arquivo? Se sim, de que maneira?

Comment: Pessoal, coloquei meu site num servidor e estou rodando o phpmailer.
Porém, quando rodo o código, a seguinte mensagem aparece.

Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in /home/petsm976/public_html/php/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 1291
Alguém pode me ajudar?